# displaying image using django and html

Tags: html, django

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but my image won't display

HTML:

```
 {% load static %}
 <img src="{% static 'images/IMG_0096.JPG' %}" alt="Mountain View"/>
```

settings.py:

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

 STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) are you running `runserver` or production deployment? 2) Do you have staticfiles in your installed apps? 3) try findstatic to see if it detects where file is - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic

Comment: using runserver, I have static files in installed apps. About to try ytsejam's suggestion, I'll let you guys know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Add `STATIC_ROOT` setting to `settings.py` to view your static files

```
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

and if you are in development environment add this settings in `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: ok I figured it out. I didn't have to do all that. The only thing that was missing was to enclose it in template blocks ie. {% block image %} {% endblock %}

Comment: still you need these to collecstatic and in the production you have to write your exact directory path to view images.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Our teacher just started talking about that part today.